# Why isn't $T_1$ space also Hausforff?

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification, separation-axioms

Definition: The topological space $X$ is $T_1$ if $ \{ x \} $ is closed for each point $x \in X$.

Proposition: The topological space $X$ is $\textit{Hausdorff}$ if and only if for each point $x  \in X$ the intersection of the closed neighbourhoods of $x$ is the one-point set $\{ x \}$.

Question: Let $X$ be a $T_1$ space. Then for every $x\in X$, $ \{x \} $ is closed and $ \overline{\{ x \}} = \{ x\} $. Thus $ \{ x \} $ is the smallest closed set containing $ \{ x \} $, that is $ \{ x \} $ is equal to the intersection of all closed sets containing $ \{ x\} $. By the above proposition $ X $ is Hausdorff. Therefore every $T_1$ space is also Hausdorff.

But this statement is said to be wrong. Where have I made my mistake?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: "closed neighbourhoods" does not mean "closed sets". for example, $\{ x \}$ is a closed set, but it might not be a closed neighbourhood of $x$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error lies in the assumption that, since $\{x\}$ is the intersection of all *sets* containing $x$, then it is also the intersection of all *closed neighborhoods* of $x$.

As an example, consider $\mathbb R$ with the topology $\tau$ for wich the open sets are $\emptyset$ and every $A\subset\mathbb R$ such that $A^\complement$ is finite. Then $(\mathbb{R},\tau$) is $T_1$, but not Hausdorff. In this case, the only closed neighborhood of a point $x$ is $\mathbb R$ itself.

Comment: Let me explain where I think I went wrong. A close set containing $x$ is not necessarily a closed neighbourhood containing $x$. Because by definition, closed neighbourhood containing $x$ needs to contain an open set containing $x$. For example in $\mathbb{R}$, $\{x\}$ is closed itself, but this is not a neighbourhood of $\{ x \}$ because $ \{ x \} $, being itself, does not contain an open neighbourhood containing $x$. Would this be a correct interpretation?

Comment: @Meagain Yes, this is correct for most topologies. In some cases, as in the case of the discrete topology, $\{x\}$ *is* a closed neighborhood of $x$.